# MySQL where search issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I cannot seem to search when I add WHERE statement below. But it works without it....

Is there something wrong?

Below is my code: Thank you.

```
SELECT DISTINCT (
                    `name`
                    ), users.id, `email`, `state_id`,
                    MAX(`total_time_driven_at_this_trip`) AS trip
                    FROM `users`
                    LEFT JOIN trip_vics ON users.id = trip_vics.user_id
                    GROUP BY `user_id`
                    WHERE name LIKE '%dan%'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to place your `where` right before `group by`

Answer (score 1):

The WHERE keyword can't be used with aggregate functions. Use HAVING instead http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp

Put WHERE before the group by if you want to apply the filter before MAX is calculated.

Comment: Where do you see usage of aggregate functions with `WHERE`?

Comment: Yes, sir! Edited to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

`having` goes with `group by`.

```
having name like '%dan%'
```

Or if you are actually trying to have a `where` clause independent of the `having` clause, it should go **between** the `join` and the `group by` statement.